# RewriteRule: Allow only numbers and a specific string comma separated

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite urls to allow only numbers and (optionally) the word "all" comma separated.

For example, something like this: mypage/23,15,all,2,all

I tried something, but there is a problem. First, this is my rule (probably syntatically wrong):

```
mypage/([\d,?(all)]+)
```

The problem here is that if a write **mypage/23** works (*correct*), **mypage/23,all** works (correct), **mypage/23,all,a** works (because it detects 'a' of 'all', so *wrong*)

How can I modify the rule to accept only the entire word "all"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage/((?:\d+|all)(,(?:\d+|all))*)/?$ target-url?str=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

There is no grouping of characters inside character class i.e. `[...]`

Comment: what does ?: stand for ?

Comment: `(?:...)` is called non-capturing group

Comment: so this will only asset the rule without capturing it am i right ?

Comment: Right so if URI is `/mypage/123,all,78` it will not capture individual numbers or `all` but outer `(...)` will capture whole thing i.e. `123,all,78` in captured group #1.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this: i think it should work**

```
/([\d]+,(all)+)

[] for optional
() for grouping
```